# How do I find invariant lines for a system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find invariant lines for the following system of differential equations:

$$x' = 2x - xy + x^3$$

$$y' = y - xy$$

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to find invariant straight lines, then the following reasoning works quite well. If straight line is flow-invariant then vector field along it is tangent to it, i.e. for straight line $y = kx$ fraction $$\frac{dy}{dt} \Big / {\frac{dx}{dt}}  \equiv k$$ along it.
So let's just plug $y = kx$ into the RHS of the system and see what happens:

$$ \frac{kx-kx^2}{2x - kx^2 +k^3x^3} = \frac{k-kx}{2 - kx + k^3 x^2} .$$

It's easy to see that only for $k =0$ this expression is equal to $k$.
So, we've found that $y = 0$ is invariant.

The only straight line that we could have missed is $ x \equiv 0$. Check by yourself that it's invariant too.